# debug an compilation error in ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've wrote the original problem [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/48035/pr2-object-manipulation-demo-code-cannot-compile/)

I'm not an experienced programmer, especially to such a big framework as ROS. So, in this post, I want to share/learn the process I'm using to debug this compilation.

> /pr2_pick_and_place_tutorial/src/simple_pick_n_place_app.cpp:92:26:
> error:
> ‘tabletop_collision_map_processing::TabletopCollisionMapProcessing::Request’
> has no member named ‘reset_static_map’

for this unknown-member bug, I:

1. looked in [CodeAPI](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/tabletop_collision_map_processing/html/namespacetabletop__collision__map__processing.html) or [SrvAPI](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/tabletop_collision_map_processing/html/srv/TabletopCollisionMapProcessing.html)
   -> even in these 2 sites, I still cannot find where "tabletop_collision_map_processing::TabletopCollisionMapProcessing::Request" is. Is it class member?? or in service's message's header??
2. looked in [Change List](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_object_manipulation/ChangeList). This list did not help in specific changes e.g. "0.4.1 (2011-03-03)
   updated for new ompl_ros_interface"
3. I also used "svn diff old_url new_url" -> [result here](http://pastebin.com/zhvN3tpR). It seems there is no change in class member of versions branches/0.4-branch-old2/, branches/0.4-branch-old1/ and the current branches/0.4-branch/ of class/namespace tabletop_collision_map_processing/

Any comments, hints about my debugging? am I lack of something to use these info source for debugging??

Much thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48153/debug-an-compilation-error-in-ros/) by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2012-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the naming it is probably a service.  A service is in two parts a request and a response. You should check out the [ROS Service Client Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0